# Ms Access Delete Query with Join and Where Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables (**tblTrainingElements** and **tblCourses**).

**tblTrainingElements** has the following fields: 
([Training Element ID], [Course ID], [Title],[Duration (min)],[Patient],[Status],[Description], [Comments],[Site],[ElementSeq])

**tblCourses** has the following relevant fields:
[Course ID], [App ID]

I need to delete all records in **tblTrainingElements** WHERE the [App ID] from **tblCourses** = "CAD".  I need to join the tables on the [Course ID] field.  Below is the SQL statement that I tried to use.  I keep getting the error message "Please specify which table you would like to delete from"

```
DELETE tblCourses.[Course Name], tblCourses.[App ID], tblTrainingElements.[Training Element ID], tblTrainingElements.[Course ID], tblTrainingElements.Title, tblTrainingElements.[Duration (min)], tblTrainingElements.Patient, tblTrainingElements.Status, tblTrainingElements.Description, tblTrainingElements.Comments, tblTrainingElements.Site, tblTrainingElements.ElementSeq

FROM tblCourses INNER JOIN tblTrainingElements ON tblCourses.[Course ID] = tblTrainingElements.[Course ID]

WHERE (((tblCourses.[App ID])="CAD"))
```

Comment: Delete query does not require column names. It needs table name. `DELETE FROM {TableName}`. Try this.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chetan.  Can you let me know exactly what to include?  I tried:

`DELETE FROM tblTrainingElements INNER JOIN tblTrainingElements ON  tblTrainingElements.[Course ID] = tblCourses.[Course ID]

WHERE (((tblCourses.[App ID])="CAD"))`

This did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete records only in tblTrainingElements table:

```
DELETE *
FROM tblTrainingElements
WHERE tblTrainingElements.[Course ID] IN (SELECT tblCourses.[Course ID] FROM tblCourses WHERE tblCourses.[App ID]="CAD" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE tc
FROM tblCourses tc 
INNER JOIN tblTrainingElements tte ON tc.[Course ID] = tte.[Course ID]
WHERE (((tc.[App ID])="CAD"))
```